# The mean value of the binary file array elements

Tags: c, file, file-io

I need to write function which will write elements of array into binary file, and after that find the mean value of elements of binary file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
double enterArray(){
    int i=0,n;
    double a[101];
    FILE* fp=fopen("niz.bin", "w");
    while(1){
        scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
        if(a[i]==-1)break;
        i++;
        if(i==100)break;
    }
    n=i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
   fwrite(a,4, n, fp);
    fclose(fp);
  return 0;   
}
double meanValue(){
  return 1;
}
int main() {
    enterArray();
    printf("%g\n", meanValue());
    return 0;
}
```

I get some random characters in niz.bin file. Could you help me fix my code?

Comment: `fwrite(a,4, n, fp);`  Does `sizeof(double) == 4` on your system? If it is, this should write the entire array (because it is `n * sizeof(double)` bytes), so no need for a loop.

Comment: Also, `FILE* fp=fopen("niz.bin", "w");` should be "wb" for "write binary".

Comment: Why would you compute the mean value afterwards?  Keep track of the information you need during the first pass of the data.  There's no reason to look at any data point twice.

Comment: <O/T> Might as well change that to `void enterArray()`. You unconditionally return 0 and don't capture it anyway ... unless that's just a placeholder for future work?

Comment: I use wb mode, for array [1,2,3,4] with fwrite(a,sizeof(double), n, fp);  I get 4 random characters? How to save them as numbers in bin file?

Comment: You are saving the data in binary format. You will not be able to view it in a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code.

You take an arbitrary number of `double`s, and then write the first n * 4 bytes in the array "repeatedly" to the file.

- You don't know for sure that `sizeof (double)` is equal to 4 bytes.
- On every iteration, you write (n * 4) bytes from the array `a` to the file.

  - What you want is, starting from `i * sizeof (double)`, write `sizeof (double)` bytes to the file (if you want to use a loop. You could simply just write (`n * sizeof (double)` bytes to the file at once)
- You use the `"w"` mode in `fopen`, which is *not* the "write binary" mode. Use `"wb"` instead.

Then, in `meanValue()`, you don't do anything. Writing/reading a 10-element `double` array to/from a binary file can be done in the following way:

```c
    /* write to the file */
    double write_arr[10] = { 0.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 };
    FILE *fp = fopen("niz.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(&write_arr, sizeof(double), 10, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    /* read from the file */
    fp = fopen("niz.bin", "rb");
    double read_arr[10];
    fread(&read_arr, sizeof (double), 10, fp);
```

Also, note that you must identify how many elements you're going to write to the file, as you write the bytes in the file without knowing how many to write in advance. As you don't write the elements immediately, you could serialize the number of elements in the first 4 bytes in the file. And when you read from it, read the first 4 bytes to know how many `double`s lying ahead.

Comment: _write the first 4 bytes in the array "repeatedly"_ With `fwrite`, the 2nd parameter is the size of the data and the 3rd parameter is the count of data items. So OP is writing the entire filled in part of the array* (n * 4 bytes), not just the first 4 bytes. *Assuming `sizeof double == 4`.

Comment: _You don't even loop_ It loops `n` times since `i` is initialized to `0` at the start of the loop and loops while `i < n`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks so much for the clarifications!

Comment: I use wb mode, for array [1,2,3,4] with fwrite(a,sizeof(double), n, fp); I get 4 random characters? How to save them as numbers in bin file?

Comment: @TortelliniTeusday How to implement this: "Note that you'll have to construct them as bare binary bits, and then interpret them as a double"

Comment: @devec I added a simple example where I write/read 10 doubles to/from a binary file. I thought that it would be more complicated than that but no, you can simply read them to the array using `fread`.